# Gradle multi-project parallel build consumes 100% of CPU time

Tags: gradle, multi-project

**System info** 
[image]

**Software info**
*OS*:
[image]
*Java*: OpenJDK 12.0.2
*Gradle*: 5.6.2

**The issue**
Building Gradle multi-project with parallel builds enabled consumes almost all the CPU time. PC is not interactable during the build process

**Steps to reproduce**
1. `git clone --recursive https://github.com/vividus-framework/vividus.git`
2. `cd vividus`
3. `./gradlew build`

Comment: You get what you have ordered. Where is the problem? You want that the build gets done as fast as possible and the consequence is that all resources are consumed.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your input :) Same set of setting on Unix-like, for example, macOS does not become not interactable. The question here how I can free some resources for Windows without changing the building approach;

Once again thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `gradle.properties` file (or `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable), try setting `org.gradle.priority=low`. On my machine it has a noticeable effect with parallel enabled, but I've also heard from some of my co-workers with older machines that this setting didn't help them too much.

You can also experiment with setting `org.gradle.workers.max`. It defaults to the number of CPU processors. Maybe set it to the number of logical processors minus one.

If it still stops you from interacting with your computer during the build, you should probably just disable parallel execution and let Gradle work on a single processor.

Comment: Thank you Bjorn, will try and report results

Comment: An example of what to fill into the `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable: `-Dorg.gradle.workers.max=10` (i.e. one is actually setting JVM option(s) there).